# Capture html content on click

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, selenium

I'm looking for a way to highlight the current html element on mouse-hover (not a specific object, anything the user encounters)
and when the user clicks the item I want to copy the content of the current html element.

How can I do that in Javascript? is there a library that I can use?

Thank you

Comment: You can do the highlighting with a simple CSS rule: `:hover`. To copy the content, you'll have to specify what you'll do with the content after. Do you mean `copy the content to the clipboard`, or `copy the content to use in a variable`, or `copy the content to insert into another HTML element.`, ... ?

Comment: @Shilly thanks, I want to copy any object (nothing predefine) and copy it to a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a hover effect, just add a `:hover` rule to your CSS sylings and add the changes in style to it. No need for JS at all. In the below example, the background color changes on hover.
Same thing can be done for any element on the page by adding the css rule to the `<body>` tag instead of a specific object:
`body *:hover { background-color: steelblue; }`

To add the click event, use JS to add an click listener to either all the items, or to the container of the items. `innerHTML` will then give you the 'content' of the HTML node that you can do anything with. In the example below, we just send the content to another function that will log it to the console.

You could write all of this into one statement, but it's usually preferred to break these things down into small pieces so you can mix n match later on when changes are needed.

```js
var addClick = function( callback ) {
  document.querySelector( '#list_items' ).addEventListener( 'click', function( event ) {
    var item = event.target;
    if ( item.nodeName === 'LI' ) callback( item.innerHTML );
  } );
};
var event_handler = function( content ) {
  console.log( 'the content of the clicked item is: ' + content );
};
addClick( event_handler );
```

```css
.list-item {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  padding: 4px;
}
.list-item:hover {
  background-color: steelblue;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list_items">
  <li class="list-item">Item 1</li>
  <li class="list-item">Item 2</li>
  <li class="list-item">Item 3</li>
  <li class="list-item">Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.execCommand` needs a user event to work. It will not work on hover, but it will on clicks and the like (mousedown, mouseup, etc.).
It seems browsers do support it consistently now.
Check out my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aldi/0bu26s8q/2/).

```
$('.image').hover(function () {
    // will not work, no user action
  $('input').select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
});

$('.image').mousedown(function () {
    //works
  document.execCommand('copy');
});
```

> Copy commands triggered from document.execCommand() will only affect the contents of the real clipboard if the event is dispatched from an event that is trusted and triggered by the user, or if the implementation is configured to allow this. How implementations can be configured to allow write access to the clipboard is outside the scope of this specification.

If you don't like jQuery, a good alternative is [clipboard.js](https://clipboardjs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

This is a way we can do this.

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".reader");
var elementArray = [...elements]
elementArray.map(function(ele){
  ele.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    this.setAttribute("style","background:yellow");
  })
  ele.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(){
    this.setAttribute("style","background:white");
  })
  ele.addEventListener('click', function(){
    alert(this.innerHTML);
  })
})
```

```html
<html>
  
<div class="reader">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse hendrerit, quam id viverra molestie, augue sapien hendrerit nisl, sed fermentum ante elit porta risus.
</div>
<p class="reader">
  Nulla tincidunt tempor tempus. Pellentesque sed nisi eget felis pulvinar sagittis. Maecenas id erat iaculis, tincidunt urna eu, viverra metus. Pellentesque in libero auctor turpis tempor mollis.
</p>
<p class="reader">
  Quisque vitae felis nisi. Praesent hendrerit sit amet nibh id scelerisque. Phasellus dictum, leo non sollicitudin pulvinar, arcu diam vestibulum leo, a eleifend libero enim et lorem.
</p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</html>
```